# Is Unity + Scala.js possible or even makes sense?

Tags: unity

I never actually used Unity (yet) and I have no possibility to check anything now, but I'm thinking about Unity for my project. I actually know C# (and hate it for some unimportant reason) and I think I'm able to learn JS or UnityScript, but I just want to use a language I know and love - Scala.

There is Scala.js - a tool that compiles Scala code to JS code. And i'm thinking: is it possible to write Scala code in some IDE (Intellij), compile it to JS code and load into Unity? And if it IS possible, what difficulties may I encounter? Does this idea even makes sense, or should I forget it, use C#/Learn JS/UnityScript or just search some Scala game frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible, because you will not have access to essential classes and namespaces provided by Unity while coding in Scala.

I suggest you to learn C# and use Unity. Because it doesn't seem like there are enough community out there using Scala to develop games, which makes the whole process difficult.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of standalone Unity SDK for such things? I mean, it seems that people can use some other IDEs when writing in C#, isn't it the same for JS?

Comment: @IlyaKhegay SDKs are designed targeting langugages, not IDEs. It has nothing to do with the IDE you use, if the language is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Unityscript scripting language is *inspired* by Javascript but has some [notable syntactical differences](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript). So trancompilation with tools designed for normal Javascript won't work. And when it *would* work, it wouldn't be a very convenient way to work because the integration into the normal Unity workflow would be quite bad.

When you want to work with Unity you should really learn C# or Unityscript.